# Property that indexes other property in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have the following types:

```
interface CellsReducer {
    source: number;
    destination: number;
    plan: string;
    duration: number;
    test: []
}

interface BarReducer {
    baz: string;
}

interface AppState {
    cells: CellsReducer;
    bar: BarReducer;
}
```

I want to write an interface with the following objects:

```
interface Props {
    store: keyof AppState;
    field: // AppState[store]
    data: // AppState[store][field]
}
```

Using Generics didn't get me anywhere. `fields` ends up with type `never` in the following example:

```
type Stores<T> = keyof T;
type Fields<T> = keyof T[Stores<T>];
type Props<TState> = {
    state: Stores<TState>;
    field: Fields<TState>
}
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need distinct type parameters for each property in the path. This allows the compiler to reason about the specific fields you specify:

```
type Props<TState, KStore extends keyof TState, KField extends keyof TState[KStore]> = {
    state: KStore;
    field: KField
    data: TState[KStore][KField]
}

let p: Props<AppState, "cells", "duration"> = {
  state: "cells",
  field: "duration",
  data: 1
}
```

The reason you get never is because when the compiler tries to expand `AppState[keyof AppState]` it will get a union `CellsReducer | BarReducer`. Since only common members of union are accesible `keyof (CellsReducer |  BarReducer)` is `never` (no keys are accessible).

The extra parameters capture the actual field, so if `KStore` is the string literal type `"cells"` `keyof AppState["cells"]` will be the keys of that particular field in app state. `KField` works similarly allowing us to correctly type `data`.

To avoid specifying the `state` and `field` values twice you can write a helper function:

```
function propertyFactory<TState>() {
  return function <KStore extends keyof TState, KField extends keyof TState[KStore]>(o: Props<TState, KStore, KField>) {
    return o;
  }
}
let p = propertyFactory<AppState>()({
  state: "cells",
  field: "duration",
  data: 1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
interface Props<T, K extends keyof T, V extends keyof T[K]> {
    state: keyof T;
    field: T[K];
    data: T[K][V]
}
```

Usage:

```
const props: Props<AppState, 'cells', 'plan'> = { /* ... */ } ;
const props: Props<AppState, 'bar', 'baz'> = { /* ... */ } ;
```